# SQL query to return results from uneven rows

Tags: sql

I am working with a database that I didn't create so cannot change it - however I am using queries to pull the data I need from it - I have a problem with a table that has entries like below.

```
12562  1  Orange
12562  2  with skin
12562  3  without skin
12562  4  flesh only
12563  1  Peach
12563  2  by box
12564  1  Strawberry
12564  2  mixed
```

I am trying to get the entries placed togther on a single row per item ID

```
12562  1  Orange  2  with skin  3  Without skin  4  flesh only
12563  1  Peach   2  by box
```

etc.

The first column being the item ID, the second the reference and the third the data - all the products have a reference 1 and 2 so getting those rows is easy - some have 3 however and I either end up with just the data for 1 and 2's or just the data for the entries that have a 1, 2 and 3

Can anyone give me a push in the right direction to a method of getting a complete result displaying all the records but 1 complete record per line ?

I am thinking it must be some kind of IF statement ..

Thanks - sorry for the ramble.

Neil

PS . sorry yes this is for use on a Microsoft SQL Server 2000 - 8.00.760 Service Pack 3

Comment: Is this a case of aggregating / concatenating strings in a specific order?

Comment: And for a varyiable number of items to be concatenated together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a left join for references that are optional:

```
select r1.Id, r1.Name, r2.Name, r3.Name, r4.Name
from Entries r1
inner join Entries r2 on r2.Id = r1.Id and r2.Reference = 2
left join EntrieS r3 on r3.Id = r1.Id and r3.Reference = 3
left join EntrieS r4 on r4.Id = r1.Id and r4.Reference = 4
where r1.Reference = 1
```

This will return null values for the fields where there is no matching record in the left join:

```
12562  Orange       with skin    without skin    flesh only
12563  Peach        by box       NULL            NULL
12564  Strawberry   mixed        NULL            NULL
```

Comment: Thanks Guffa - works well - really appreciate your time on this ;o)

Answer (score 2):

You should use the PIVOT (*for SQL Server since you do not specify in your question*)

```
SELECT 
       id, [1], [2], [3], [4]
FROM    ( SELECT   
           id, data, reference
          FROM  yourtable
        ) p PIVOT ( min(data) FOR [reference] 
                      IN ([1],[2],[3],[4])
                  ) AS pvt
```

result is

```
id      1             2             3                   4
12562   Orange        with skin     without skin        flesh only
12563   Peach         by box        NULL                NULL
12564   strawberry    mixed         NULL                NULL
```

---

**Update** 
*For Pre-2005 SQL Server*

Run the stored procedure found at http://www.sqlteam.com/article/dynamic-cross-tabs-pivot-tables

and the use it with

```
execute crosstab 
          'select id from yourtable group by id', 
          'min(data)',
          'reference',
          'yourtable'
```

Comment: I feel like a real idiot with this - that or it's one of those days .. thanks still getting an error - unable to parse and then a syntax error - will recheck everything.

Comment: @Neil, what MS-SQL-Server version you use (*PIVOT is only available on 2005 and up*) ? (*and also you need to use your own field and table names..*)

Comment: Aha that would explain it DOH - Microsoft SQL Server  2000 - 8.00.760 Service Pack 3 - probably would have been good to mention that to you huh ;o) - thanks for your time - any suggestions ?

Comment: OK Guffa's answer below works for SQL Server 2000 - and looks like PIVOT above would be good for 2005 etc. - thanks all

Comment: @Neil, just updated my answer for pre-2005 sql server using a stored procedure that mimics the Pivot concept..

Answer (score 0):

Oracle 11g has a function [LISTAGG](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/functions087.htm) for this.

There may be something similar in other DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using mysql, you can use [group_concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(reference, " ", data) SEPARATOR " ") as result
FROM tablename
GROUP BY id
```